# Vaadin Flow and Method Security @PreAuthorize on Views

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Dear all I am working with Vaadin Flow 24 and Spring Security 6. I like to use Method Security in my views, but it is not working (seems to get ignored). I am wondering if this is supported on Vaadin Views and if not by default if there is a way to get it working.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class BackendSecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {
 ...
}
```

```
@SpringComponent
@Route("backend/users") 
@PageTitle("Backend | Users")
@PermitAll
@Slf4j
public class BackendUsersView extends VerticalLayout {
 ...

    // ==>  Issue : the PreAuthorize seems to be ignored on Vaadin Views?

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    private void saveUser(BackendUserForm.SaveEvent event) {
        userRepository.save(event.getUser());
        updateList();
        closeEditor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, private methods are not intercepted, and the same states for annotated methods called by non secured methods of the same class.
You may move the save logic in another class (e.g. a service), have the instance injected into the view and call the annotated method on the service from the view